# Advantages vs. Disadvantages of sending email through Google/Gmail instead of from my server

Tags: php, email, gmail, google-apps, swiftmailer

I've read a lot of questions on stack about people who want to change their mail classes (i.e. swiftmailer) to send the emails with SMTP using their Google Apps server/email address.

The only real benefit to this that I can see is that a copy is placed in Gmail's sent folder.  I overcome this currently (without SMTP) by just BCCing an email from my server to keep copies of everything that goes out (i.e. mail@whatever.com).

Does sending through Gmail's SMTP server help with Spam or that annoying "Google doesn't think this was sent by this server"?  Is there anything else I'm overlooking?

Thanks all.

(and yes, my domain is a hosted by Google Apps for email/calendar/etc... the MX records are all set and functional).

Answer (score 3):

Emails are under all kinds of anti-spam scrutiny by major email providers. By sending them through Google you can probably use the work that Google has already done.

See this article: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

You may also consider using a service like [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/).

Comment: Great article.  Are a lot of these features like DKIM for example - included in SwiftMailer?

Comment: These features are on the layer "below" SwiftMailer and must be implemented on the mail and DNS servers. If you use SwiftMailer to connect to a server that has these features, then it's supported :-)

Answer (score 1):

Advantages:

1. E-mail id with your domain name like yourname@yourdomain.com.
2. Ulimited email id with your domain name if you have your own server.

Disadvantage:

1. Develop or purchase email gateway for better ui and service.